# MySQL Order by id, unless the record has a parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm using Laravel (and MySQL of course) to build a pages module, a page can have 1 parent

This is my current data, and using `order_by="id"` it's also returned like this.

```
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | NULL      |
|  2 | NULL      |
|  3 | 1         |
|  4 | 1         |
+----+-----------+
```

**Now I'm wondering if it's possible to have a result set where the children are ordered underneath their parent.** Which would render the following result

```
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | NULL      |
|  3 | 1         |
|  4 | 1         |
|  2 | NULL      |
+----+-----------+
```

### Thoughts

Maybe it is possible to generate an order_by query that orders by id, but assigns a temporary id in a temp column, in between the others, in case the row has a parent_id?

So ideally the 2 children (3, 4) of the parent (1) are shown just below it.

Comment: Do you know the nested set model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model to represent trees?

Comment: order by the `parent_id` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)function:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(`parent_id`,`id`),`parent_id` is not null
```

P.S.   `,parent_id is not null` is needed for the case even `(2,1)` inserted instead of `(2,null)` in the order of `VALUES(2,1),(1,null),(3,1),(4,1)`(*special thanks to @splash58*)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=87143571e7f3b98c78658242b917ffd1)</kbd>

Comment: Ahhh, coalesce... I always forget about that.  Super useful function!

Comment: That's amazing, and easy!

Comment: Nobody said that parent has id less  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8d657f10f09f584bbdeed26a926d185f

Comment: May be,  `ORDER BY parent_id is not null, coalesce(parent_id,id)` but i'm not sure